# The meaning of the word 'prolific' as used in a sentence

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> I feel as if this event in my life is prolific or has a profound spiritual nature.

Is this a correct sentence for the word 'prolific'?

Comment: I think that's wrong but I'm not sure. If it's right, it's a more uncommon use for the word. Have you checked a dictionary for other meanings of *prolific*? Usually it means something like "producing a lot of something", like a *prolific writer* is someone who writes a lot of books.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's perfectly fine in this context.  Although others may disagree with the use of the word, as it means "present in large numbers", or "producing many offspring", words like this are often misapplied or given additional nuance when used in new situations.

However, you might find that a more familiar word for your spiritual context is *abundant*, although it is pretty overused.